# Problem on using ODP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I've successfully used [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1.0)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html) to connect oracle from .Net. (in reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll version was 2.112.1.0).

But when I installed ODP.NET and when I am trying to connect to oracle, it gives me an error: "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified".

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This usually occurs when your oracle client is not in the PATH of your computer.

Make sure that the `PATH` environment variable contains both `<Oracle client path>` and `<Oracle client path>\bin`.

Also, this can happen if the `SID` of the database you want to connect to is simply not defined in the `tnsnames.ora` file under your oracle client installation path. If I recall correctly - it is under `<Oracle client path>\network\admin\tnsnames.ora`

**Edit:** The registry should contain an ORACLE entry set under: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\`
There should be a key named `HOME0` with string values: **ORACLE_HOME** and **ID**. I assume there are other values required as well - but those two I'm sure of. Check that **ORACLE_HOME** points correctly to the oracle client location.

Comment: PATH environment variable contains both value and service name is defined correctly.

Comment: There should also be a registry entry, but I don't recall what it was currently. Sorry - I'll re-post if I remember.

Comment: did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Copy the TNSNAMES.ORA from the oracle home that works into the Oracle home that does not.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/odt-faq-085407.html#ORA-12154:_TNS:could_not_resolve_the