# Using Entity Framework with Oracle

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net, toad

I installed the 32 bit version of ODAC (11.2.0.2.50) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html) in an attempt to use the Entity Framework with Oracle.

As soon as this is installed my data connection to the database fails in Server Explorer with the following error:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I can fire up TOAD and view my database fine, however when I was in there I clicked on the 'Home Editor' and was presented with this:

[image]

which I can only assume is related somehow.  I checked with the answer [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058744/problem-on-using-odp-net) but to no avail.

Any ideas as to the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end all I had to do was **reboot my machine**.  Typical!

Answer (score 0):

Check ORACLE is using TNSNAMES as a means of resolving details by going through the Oracle "Net Manager". Add your connection through the NET manager and check it appears in the TNSNAMES file as you were expecting.

Also I've previously had this problem and resolved with:

1. Long SID instance names - try truncating your DBNAME if you can (to around 6 characters)
2. Domain names. in your TNS, add the domain onto your identifier, eg.

DINST.domain.co.uk =
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myServer)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = DINST)
    )
  )

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12451 means that the database alias you're using is not configured in your TNSNAMES.ora file

One option is to use the "EZCONNECT" ("Easy Connect") method by specifying [host]/[sid] as your database connection which should avoid TNSNAMES lookup alltogether